# jQuery validation dependency expression with numeric field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, numeric

I have this snippet:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sal_cart" id="sal_cart">
<input type="text" name="sal_unit_price" id="sal_unit_price" class="required">
```

sal_unit_price can be numeric or string, but it's always required (can't be blank).
So far so good.
If sal_cart is checked, then sal_unit_price MUST be numeric (strings are no more allowed)
According to [jQuery Validation dependency-expression](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression), I put this:

```
$('#form1').validate({
    rules: {
        sal_unit_price: { number: '#sal_cart:checked' },
    },
    messages: {
        sal_unit_price: { number: 'Please fill in a number' },
    }
});
```

but it doesn't work: even if the checkbox is NOT checked, it still says that it requires a number
Please, can you spot what's wrong with this?

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cWD8j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you have used only applies to the required rule, for the other rules you need a longer syntax, passing in an object with **param** and **depends** properties

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erUdF/)

```
$('#form1').validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        sal_unit_price: { 
            number: {
                param : true,
                depends: '#sal_cart:checked'
            }
       },
    },
    messages: {
        sal_unit_price: { number: 'Please fill in a number' },
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works very well! Please, can you point me where can I find this in the online documentation?

Comment: I don't think it is documented, although there is an example of using a dependency function here http://khaidoan.wikidot.com/jquery-validation